# Git workflow issue. Remove a merged branch from another branch

Tags: git

I have a feature branch that has been merged multiple times with a development branch over the the last few weeks. Before we merge it to master branch we want to remove the feature branches code thats been merged into the development branch over the last few weeks. Is there a unified way of doing this?

The merges were created with --no-ff, so the commits in the new branch should have their own objects.

```
_______ master ______________________________
                  \                   /
                   \                 /
                    \__hofix-1_____C/
                                    \
_ development _______________________\____________
\                    /          /         /
 \                  /          /         /
  \_feature-test__A/_________B/________D/
```

So I want to remove the merged commits A, B and D from development, while still retaining hotfix-1, merge C, and still continue to work on the feature branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, I don't think you need anything as heavy as rebase, revert and the like.  You can simply do this:

1. look through the development log to find the commit hash just before merge A, and create a new branch there called "new-dev":

   git checkout -b new-dev somecommithash
2. now merge in C from the hotfix-1 branch:

   git merge C

... and you're done.  new-dev branch now has the contents of development, merged with C, minus A B and D.

If you now want to make the developer branch point to the same place as the new-dev branch, that's as simple as:

```
git branch -f developer new-dev
```

But for safety you might want to mark the old developer branch location with a tag or branch before forcibly moving it to the new location.

Comment: ok. If I create that new branch before the first merge with feature branch, could I then just cherry-pick the commits i want to keep. I  maybe have dozen commits i want to retain. Could I maybe revert the commits I don't want rather than cherry-pick the commits i do, if that is cleaner/quicker? I guess I don't mind cherry-picking, as long as the history is intact and doesn't affect the other developers history. Also, this is probably a stupid question, when tagging, do I tag after or before cherry-picking.

Comment: well the 2 things to realize are 1) you're ALWAYS adding, never subtracting, and 2) branches are nothing but a pointer to a particular commit.  You can move the pointer freely however you like.  So "reverting" a change is really just moving the pointer back to a previous commit.  And cherry-picking is really just adding new commits that match the cherry-picked one to a new location.  Now the purpose of the tag is simply to maintain a pointer to where your branch used to point, in case you ever want to find that spot again. You may as well do it before the cherry-pick but it doesnt matter

Answer (score 4):

The question is somewhat fuzzy. You have a dev branch and want to unmerge several incoming merges, leaving the rest? If so, you can use `rebase -i -p` with some low point, deleting the merge commits form the todo list.  Note that you shall re-check all the commits you pulled stuff under, as next work might build on it.

Another approach is to use `git revert` on the top for the unwanted changes. It gets the final result done, but likely leave you with a poor quality history.

Comment: You are correct. Will either of these solutions cause issues with branches being tracked by other users? That is, if they try and merge back into development, will it cause conflicts or will branches diverge. I think the rebase would.